# Is it possbile that request is sent but response is failed?

Tags: http, angular, network-programming

I'm new in programming and recently writing a hobby angular 2 app that make a network request within the application, The request is AJAX with `http` object.

During writing the application, I wonder.. is it possible the request that made by client application is accepted and processed by the server, but the server failed to make a response to the client due to connection error?

If that possible, how do I avoid multiple request being processed?

Comment: *I wonder.. is it possible the request that made by client application is accepted and processed by the server, but the server failed to make a response to the client due to connection error?* - yes. But why would 'no response' lead to multiple requests being processed?

Comment: How the client know the request is processed successfully or not if the response is empty? I assume empty response is an error, and when user press 'try again' it will make the same request, which mean the same request will be processed twice (in case the first one is successful)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler When does it happen? Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @HFX - if the client is on a weak WiFi or cellular internet connection, the connection might drop out after sending the request and before getting a response. If the client is on a limited connection and the request uses the last of their quota and the response is blocked by the carrier. If there is a proxying firewall in the middle (e.g. a company firewall) which allows the request, but blocks the response because it (wrongly) triggers some kind of intrusion prevention filter so the client never sees it. If the server is low on resources and the OS forces a service or open socket to close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) model, HTTP is **[application level layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer)** which is transported over **[transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) i.e. TCP** to the peer for sending OR receiving messages.

Transport layer has following attributes: reliable/non-reliable, connection/connection-less, flow-control, congestion, etc. To support these features TCP or UDP protocols are used.

Since we are transporting HTTP PDU, even if PDU gets dropped (due to various reasons), it will be retransmitted as TCP support sliding-window. And only after receiving FIN (final) from peer the connection is closed. Until then you can consider all your PDU will be transported faithfully. TCP also has timeouts and retries, they are configurable too.

But if server is dead or not responding then you will get appropriate error message while making HTTP request, because mere TCP connection itself will fail. Following are well defined [error messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Enable logging OR console traces to notice these errors.

Comment: So the duplication will not occur under tcp / udp right? what is PDU? sorry, I'm new at this stuff, but I think i got your point

Comment: @tronic, duplication will never happen. In networking specifications (like: RFC or IETF or 3GPP) PDU is called [Protocol Data Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit).

Answer (score 0):

you can check the connection at the time of response back.

Please also check the below points

1. Check the return type from the server.
2. Is your angular program is expecting the same type of response which is returned from the server?

Comment: The server should be returning json and there is `success` boolean property which indicate the request process status

Comment: can you please try as -  return new JsonResponse("success ",""); and try to print the response at the angular side if it is getting something.

Comment: the `success` is undefined, that will equivalent to `false` since i use `if (success)` to check it